# The intersection of *-semigroups with I-semigroups is the class of inverse semigroups?

Tags: semigroups

Howie in his *Fundamentals of Semigroup Theory*, 2nd ed., p. 103 writes

> The class of U-semigroups for which the unary operation satisfies the conditions both for a *-semigroup and for an I-semigroup is in fact the class of
>   *inverse semigroups*, which will be the subject of Chapter 5.

where

- U-semigroups are defined as having a unary operation satisfying $x^{**}=x$,
- I-semigroups are U-semigroups in which $xx^*x = x$ also holds,
- *-semigroups are U-semigroups in which $(xy)^* = y^*x^*$.

But there's a class of semigroups (albeit not discussed in Howie) introduced by  Nordahl and Scheiblich, which they called *regular *-semigroups* that seems to be the proper intersection of I-semigroups and *-semigroups. They give the following example of a regular *-semigroup that's not an inverse semigroup: given a set $A$ form a semigroup on $A × A$ with the semigroup product defined by $(a, b)(c, d) = (a, d)$ and the involution being $(a, b)^* = (b, a)$. It's utterly trivial to verify that this semigroup satisfies all three of the above equations so it is both a I-semigroup and *-semigroup.

To see that's not an inverse semigroup, the equation [which actually turns out to be an identity]: $(a, b)(p, q)(a, b) = (a, q)(a, b) = (a, b)$ with unknown $(p, q)$ accepts as solution any element of the semigroup. And any solution also verifies the "dual" equation/identity $(p, q)(a, b)(p, q) = (p, q)$. So this semigroup is a regular semigroup that is as far from an inverse semigroup as possible (in that class inverses must be unique), well, unless $A$ has single element.

So, is the statement I quoted from Howie's book simply erroneous or should it be interpreted in some way that eludes me? (There doesn't seem to be an errata for the book, by the way.)

---

In Chapter 5 [p. 145], Howie defines an inverse semigroup as an I-semigroup $S$ such that, additionally, for all $x, y \in S$, $xx^*yy^*=yy^*xx^*$. Howie then proves correctly that this definition is equivalent with the [more typical] definition that every element has a unique inverse [in Theorem 5.1.1(4)]. He then proves [Proposition 5.1.2(1)] that in an inverse semigroup $(xy)^* = y^*x^*$ also holds, so an inverse semigroup is also a *-semigroup.

Howie doesn't attempt however to back up his claim from p. 103 that a semigroup that is both a *-semigroup and a I-semigroup is inverse, and it's easy to see that in an I-semigroup that's also a *-semigroup, $xx^*yy^*=yy^*xx^*$ may not hold: in the semigroup example [rectangular band] of Nordahl and Scheiblich: $(a,b)(b,a)(c,d)(d,c) = (a,c)$ but $(c,d)(d,c)(a,b)(b,a) = (c,a)$, so these aren't equal unless the semigroup is trivial.

So there no surprises in Chapter 5, i.e. the problematic statement is localized on p. 103.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a mistake, there are several well-known and much studied classes of regular *-semigroups. At the end of page 102, Howie even writes so "$a^{-1}$ is an inverse of $a$", not "$a^{-1}$ is the unique inverse of $a$". Using $a^{-1}$ to mean "an inverse" rather than "the unique inverse" could easily lead to confusion.